# Trying to understand complexity of this big0 notation

Tags: big-o

T(n) = n(T(n-1) + T(n-1)) + o(1) . The answer as per the book is o(n!) I am not able to come to this solution. Can someone give some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's my take on this:

```
T(n) = n(T(n-1) + T(n-1)) + O(1)
T(n) = n(2T(n-1)) + O(1)
T(n) = nT(n-1) + O(1) // constants are not included in complexity. O(n + k) = O(k)
T(n) = nT(n-1)
```

This is a factorial complexity.

Comment: ahh gotcha! I did not see it in this way. Thanks for the guidance :)

Comment: Although you can ignore constant coefficients in a big-O expression, you cannot do the same in a recursive relation.